# How can I delete a Firestore field, using whereField?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a field within a document, when the field "uid" matches the Current User's ID. I'm pretty stuck on this, and would appreciate any help. I detail, below, my code and how my database is set up.

```
@IBAction func deleteAccountButtonIsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let username = usernameTextField.placeholder
    
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR MAIN SETTINGS 136")
        } else {
            db.collection("FollowerList").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID!).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                for snapshot in snapshot?.documents {
                
                }
            }
            }
                }
)}
```

My Database has a collection "FollowerList", with documents named with the User's UID. Within these documents is a "uid" field, with the value of the User's UID.
Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the Job:

```
func deleteAccountButtonIsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let username = usernameTextField.placeholder
        
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERROR MAIN SETTINGS 136")
            } else {
                db.collection("FollowerList").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID!).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let snapshot = snapshot?.documents {
                        for doc in snapshot {
                            
                            //Do delete
                            db.collection("FollowerList").document(doc.documentID).updateData([
                                "fieldToDelete": FieldValue.delete(),
                            ]) { err in
                                if let err = err {
                                    print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                                } else {
                                    print("Document successfully updated")
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )}
```

One would think it could work like this:
But it doesn't as a value of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no member 'updateData'.

```
func deleteAccountButtonIsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let username = usernameTextField.placeholder
        
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERROR MAIN SETTINGS 136")
            } else {
                db.collection("FollowerList").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID!).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let snapshot = snapshot?.documents {
                        for doc in snapshot {
                            
                            // How one would think it works but it doesnt
                            doc.updateData([
                                "capital": FieldValue.delete(),
                            ]) { err in
                                if let err = err {
                                    print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                                } else {
                                    print("Document successfully updated")
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )}
```

See this page for further information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#swift

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly